# I have a remote origin branch. Locally I have a master branch and test branch. How to pull to test branch without committing?

Tags: git

I want to pull remote changes to the test branch.
My workflow -

```
git stash save 
git pull origin test
git stash pop
```

I think by using this I'll get fresh copy of the remote branch while my changes will also be applied on top of it.
Is this correct? Or should I follow any other method

Also when I finally commit I'll do the following-

```
git add . 
git commit -m "Committing changes"
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Is this workflow correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely technically - yes, your current approach would serve your needs. But since you are asking about workflow and other approaches...

There is no one correct workflow with git. **If you are on a team**, follow the agreed upon team workflow, whatever that is. **If you are working alone**, do what's most suitable to your way of working.

---

There are other ways as well:

You can commit your changes and put them in a separate/temporary branch. Then you can merge/rebase that branch and continue your work.

By the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things), it considers this branching approach better:

> If you would like to keep the changes you’ve made to that file but still need to get it out of the way for now, we’ll go over stashing and branching in Git Branching; these are generally better ways to go.

Stashing might cause immediate conflicts, once you start applying the stash. That's not a bad thing, but it's worth noting it. Also, note that if you `drop` and have conflicts, you won't loose you work, so it's somewhat of a safe operation.

**Note:** Keep in mind that `stash pop` will **remove** your stash, you might want to `apply` it before you drop your work.

Comment: And about the commit and rebasing? I am doing these two also from the test branch

Comment: Git documentation is your best friend :), but, generally yes, on your test branch you would then rebase what you've pulled from origin. That way you'll put your "temp" changes on top of your remote changes you've pulled.

Comment: I have a doubt. Shouldn't it be git pull --rebase origin test instead of git pull --rebase origin master?

Comment: You first create a temporary branch, which contains your local changes you want to save and work on in a later point. Then you go back to your branch from which you branched off (this can either be test or master), pull the commits you have to pull. Then you go back to your temporary branch and you can rebase/merge it. So.... you are always working on either `test` and `temp-test` or `master` and `temp-master`. Merging `test` into `master` and vice-versa is a totally different question.